# Map add element and return two instead of 1

Tags: scala

Imagine that I have the following List l. Is it possible by using map to return a list similar to the result below but if let's say the number is 2 to return the result twice? e.g.

> l.map( x => if (x=2) (return twice) x*2 )

so the resulted list should be

> List(2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 10)

instead of the one presented below.

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3,4,5)

scala> l.map( x => x*2 )
res60: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `.flatMap`

```
l.flatMap { 
  case 2 => Seq(4,4)
  case x => Seq(x*2)
}
```